# Calling a C++ Function that takes pointers from C#

Tags: c#, .net, c++, interop

I have a function in C++ that returns pointer values​​:

```
fPosFirst( int &aId, char *aNname, char *aDirectory );
```

But I have to pass this to C#. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is VB.NET syntax, but you should be able to convert this to C# easily enough.

```
Private Declare Ansi Sub fPosFirst lib "libraryname" (ByRef aId as Integer, byval aName as StringBuilder, byval aDirectory as StringBuilder)
```

Now if aNname and aDirectory should have been const char *, you can use String instead of StringBuilder and it gets a lot easier.

Answer (score 3):

You need to examine [P/Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) (Platform Invoke), a way to call native-code functions (C and C++) from .Net/Managed Code (C#).